# Response.Redirect behaves different from within UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

Everywhere in my web application i use redirects like these:

```
Response.Redirect("~/SearchResults.aspx", true);
```

And this always takes me to the right page. http://localhost/myapp/SearchResults.aspx

But now i'm doing this in the onclick event of a button that sits in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel and it tries to bring me to the following address:
http://localhost/myapp/%2fmyapp%2fSearchResults.aspx

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i found the real answer to this problem. It turned out that it was not the fix that i posted before. Although that was a good workaround at that time, the real problem was that the CMS i'm working in brings an outdated version of **MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js**. Updating this script, solved all of my async-postback-redirect problems.

Below is the workaround in case you just want a button that does a full postback and redirect from within an update panel.

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRedirectButton" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is supported by default without option 2 in the blog below.
There are several solutions though.

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-responseredirect-in-aspnet-ajax.html

Also I've read you can put a button in there as well surrounded by a <trigger> element and in your button_click do the redirect but never tried that method:

http://www.freejobsreference.com/dotnetforums/210-Response-Redirect-not-working-error-if-button-is-inside-Update-Panel.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Response.Redirect should work in an update panel, its one of the known exceptions.

However, time was at least, that it wouldn't work if you didn't have a block similar to this in your web.config:

```
   <httpModules>
       <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
```

I don't use ASP.Net ajax anymore and I'm on my Mac so I can't test if this is the right version or not, but this should hopefully put you on the right track.

Edit: This link has 2 other possible solutions:

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-responseredirect-in-aspnet-ajax.html

Comment: hey I had that link here first : )

Comment: eh ? you answered 19 minute ago, I answered 21 minutes ago :D

Comment: I tried them all, but none of them seems to work. The ScriptModule was already included in my project. The redirect method results in a warning that talks about a potentially dangerous Url and the JavaScript solution does .. nothing.

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using , but I'd attach your equivalent of Firefox and look for any error codes returning from the Asynchronous call. Adams second suggestion is worth a try too.

Comment: @Russ - your edit at 21 included the link, your original didnt - mine did. My edit added the second link in my posting WIN!  : )

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of the above suggestions but with no luck. The problem is still there, so now i've worked around it, by taking the button that does the redirect out of the update panel. After thinking about this for a while i've concluded that this is the most logical place for the button as well, because it doesn't call an update of the panel, but an update of the whole page.